# How to pass dynamic statement into function?

Tags: lua

This what I try:

```
local data = {
    {cond1 = 'yes', cond2 = 'yes', nums = 7, results = 'no', average = 9.5},
    {cond1 = 'yes', cond2 = 'no', nums = 12, results = 'no', average = 15},
    {cond1 = 'no', cond2 = 'yes', nums = 18, results = 'yes', average = 26.5},
    {cond1 = 'no', cond2 = 'yes', nums = 35, results = 'yes', average = 36.5},
    {cond1 = 'yes', cond2 = 'yes', nums = 38, results = 'yes', average = 44},
    {cond1 = 'yes', cond2 = 'no', nums = 50, results = 'no', average = 66},
    {cond1 = 'no', cond2 = 'no', nums = 83, results = 'no'},
}

function split_data(data, root_node, branch_node, root_condition_function, branch_condition_function)
    local true_node = {true_value = 0, false_value = 0}
    local false_node = {true_value = 0, false_value = 0}

    for _, entry in ipairs(data) do
        if root_condition_function(entry, root_node) then
            if branch_condition_function(entry, branch_node) then
                true_node.true_value = true_node.true_value + 1
            else
                true_node.false_value = true_node.false_value + 1
            end
        else
            if branch_condition_function(entry, branch_node) then
                false_node.true_value = false_node.true_value + 1
            else
                false_node.false_value = false_node.false_value + 1
            end
        end
    end

    return true_node, false_node
end

-- Statement for root node/string node
local function root_string_condition(entry, root_node)
    return entry[root_node] == 'yes'
end

-- Statement for numeric root node
local function root_numeric_condition(entry, root_node, branch_node)
    local nums = entry[root_node]
    local average = entry[branch_node]

    -- Check for nil values
    if nums == nil or average == nil then
        return false
    end

    return tonumber(nums) < tonumber(average), tonumber(nums) >= tonumber(average)
end

-- Statement for branch node
local function branch_condition(entry, branch_node)
    return entry[branch_node] == 'yes'
end

-- Example usage for string condition
local trueNodeStr, falseNodeStr = split_data(data, 'cond1', 'results', root_string_condition, branch_condition)

-- Print the results for string condition
print("String Condition Results:")
print(string.format("Cond1 True  - True Value: %d, False Value: %d", trueNodeStr.true_value, trueNodeStr.false_value))
print(string.format("Cond1 False - True Value: %d, False Value: %d", falseNodeStr.true_value, falseNodeStr.false_value))

-- Example usage for numeric condition
local trueNodeNum, falseNodeNum = split_data(data, 'nums', 'results', root_numeric_condition, branch_condition)

-- Print the results for numeric condition
print("\nNumeric Condition Results:")
print(string.format("Nums True  - True Value: %d, False Value: %d", trueNodeNum.true_value, trueNodeNum.false_value))
print(string.format("Nums False - True Value: %d, False Value: %d", falseNodeNum.true_value, falseNodeNum.false_value))
```

The results:

```
String Condition Results:
Cond1 True  - True Value: 1, False Value: 3
Cond1 False - True Value: 2, False Value: 1

Numeric Condition Results:
Nums True  - True Value: 0, False Value: 0
Nums False - True Value: 3, False Value: 4
```

Why for Numeric results give incorrect result?

Expected results:

```
Numeric Condition Results:
Nums True  - True Value: 0, False Value: 1
Nums False - True Value: 3, False Value: 3
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to pass on `'average'`?

Comment: no, i pass the condition statement to root node, as you can see if for string function when its pass the statement function to the root node its gaave correct results, but not for numeric statement function.

Comment: No? I meant the string at the 6th to last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this call:

```lua
local trueNodeNum, falseNodeNum = split_data(data, 'nums', 'results', root_numeric_condition, branch_condition)
```

`split_data` only passes two arguments to `root_numeric_condition` (`root_condition_function`)

```lua
if root_condition_function(entry, root_node) then
```

where three are expected:

```lua
local function root_numeric_condition(entry, root_node, branch_node)
```

So in `root_numeric_condition`

```lua
local average = entry[branch_node]
```

will always be `nil`, and the function will always return `false`.

Given the variable name, it looks like you are actually trying to access the `average` field of the `entry` table, but

```lua
return tonumber(nums) < tonumber(average), tonumber(nums) >= tonumber(average)
```

the multiple return values of `root_numeric_condition` and the use of `tonumber` on what one would expect to already be numbers makes it rather unclear what your intentions are.

---

As a start, `split_data` can be refactored into:

```lua
local function split_data(data, root, branch, root_condition, branch_condition)
    local results = {
        { true_value = 0, false_value = 0 },
        { true_value = 0, false_value = 0 }
    }

    for _, entry in ipairs(data) do
        local b1 = root_condition(entry, root) and 1 or 2
        local b2 = branch_condition(entry, branch) and 'true_value' or 'false_value'

        results[b1][b2] = 1 + results[b1][b2]
    end

    return results[1], results[2] -- or table.unpack(results)
end
```

And purely based on your expectations, one would assume something like

```lua
local function root_numeric_condition(entry, root)
    return not entry.average or entry[root] > entry.average 
end
```

Comment: your code gave correct results for current data, Nums True  - True Value: 0, False Value: 1
Nums False - True Value: 3, False Value: 3. but if i change one of entry value, for example nums = 7 to be nums = 17, its should be gave results: Nums True  - True Value: 0, False Value: 0
Nums False - True Value: 3, False Value: 4, but its gave Nums True  - True Value: 0, False Value: 2
Nums False - True Value: 3, False Value: 2. why its happend?

Comment: `root_numeric_condition` controls whether  the first or second table in `results` is used. With my example, and your data, `root_numeric_condition` primarily returns `false`, as all the `nums` fields are less than the `average` fields (except that it returns `true` where the `average` field is absent). Changing `7` to `17` makes that `nums > average` *true*, and the first `results` table is used. Again, the `root_numeric_condition` I have written is a complete fabrication to match your expected results - I still have no understanding of the purpose of your data, or how it should be processed.

Comment: sorry my bad, i have miss intepreting the root logic, the statement that should i to apply for root node is each average values compared to all nums value